# SP Returning different result sets for same parameter

Tags: java, sql-server, database, jdbc

I am facing this strange problem. 
When I execute a MS SQL stored procedure from my application through JDBC driver it returns me only 7 rows for particular set of parameters.
Now If I run this same stored procedure with same set of parameters on MS SQL Management Studio I get 7000 rows.

This is happening for a particular set of parameter for all other parameter options both are returning same set of results.

I am unable to identify the problem, Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're passing in the parameters using different data types, which could be causing an issue. (But if you can post code, I'll edit this response if it looks to be a different situation.)

Answer (score 0):

What is the data type for parameter?

One such example is when you pass Java.SQL.Date OR TimeStamp. Both will be accepted by SQL DATETIME field but will wield different results.